# Juniper EX4200-48t LACP on 10GB module not working

Tags: juniper, lacp

I'm new to Juniper products and I bough two older EX4200-48t. I setup virtual chassis and add a few LAGs with LACP. All LAGs on copper connections works fine but on the 10GB module not. The module is part number 740-021309 (10GBASE-LR 10km 1310nm 70C). ae11 is an LAG with LACP and two 1G copper uplinks and ae48 is the LAG with the two SPF+ modules. Both LAGs are connected to the provider switch. I don't know which switch they are using. They only told me, that LACP is in active mode and the don't know why there is a problem.

Config:

```
   ge-0/0/11 {
       ether-options {
           802.3ad ae11;
       }
   }
   ge-1/0/11 {
       ether-options {
           802.3ad ae11;
       }
   }
   ae11 {
       aggregated-ether-options {
           lacp {
               passive;
           }
       }
       unit 0 {
           family ethernet-switching {
               port-mode access;
               vlan {
                   members 10;
               }
           }
       }
   }
...
   xe-0/1/0 {
       ether-options {
           802.3ad ae48;
       }
   }
   xe-1/1/0 {
       ether-options {
           802.3ad ae48;
       }
   }
   ae48 {
       enable;
       aggregated-ether-options {
           lacp {
               passive;
           }
       }
       unit 0 {
           family ethernet-switching {
               port-mode trunk;
               vlan {
                   members [ 10 230 1001-1002 1600 2551 ];
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Status:

```
cli show interfaces ae48
Physical interface: ae48, Enabled, Physical link is Down
 Interface index: 155, SNMP ifIndex: 743
 Link-level type: Ethernet, MTU: 1514, Speed: Unspecified, BPDU Error: None,
 MAC-REWRITE Error: None, Loopback: Disabled, Source filtering: Disabled,
 Flow control: Disabled, Minimum links needed: 1,
 Minimum bandwidth needed: 1bps
 Device flags   : Present Running
 Interface flags: Hardware-Down SNMP-Traps Internal: 0x0
 Current address: 78:19:f7:81:0d:33, Hardware address: 78:19:f7:81:0d:33
 Last flapped   : 2020-10-21 21:18:12 CEST (5d 06:34 ago)
 Input rate     : 0 bps (0 pps)
 Output rate    : 0 bps (0 pps)

 Logical interface ae48.0 (Index 96) (SNMP ifIndex 744)
   Flags: Device-Down SNMP-Traps 0x0 Encapsulation: ENET2
   Statistics        Packets        pps         Bytes          bps
   Bundle:
       Input :             0          0             0            0
       Output:             0          0             0            0
   Adaptive Statistics:
       Adaptive Adjusts:          0
       Adaptive Scans  :          0
       Adaptive Updates:          0
   Protocol eth-switch                 
     Flags: Trunk-Mode      

cli show interfaces ae11
Physical interface: ae11, Enabled, Physical link is Up
 Interface index: 130, SNMP ifIndex: 667
 Link-level type: Ethernet, MTU: 1514, Speed: 2Gbps, BPDU Error: None,
 MAC-REWRITE Error: None, Loopback: Disabled, Source filtering: Disabled,
 Flow control: Disabled, Minimum links needed: 1,
 Minimum bandwidth needed: 1bps
 Device flags   : Present Running
 Interface flags: SNMP-Traps Internal: 0x0
 Current address: 78:19:f7:81:0d:0e, Hardware address: 78:19:f7:81:0d:0e
 Last flapped   : 2020-10-21 23:23:49 CEST (5d 04:29 ago)
 Input rate     : 3247800 bps (329 pps)
 Output rate    : 208216 bps (167 pps)

 Logical interface ae11.0 (Index 71) (SNMP ifIndex 693)
   Flags: Up SNMP-Traps 0x0 Encapsulation: ENET2
   Statistics        Packets        pps         Bytes          bps
   Bundle:
       Input :         59356          0       5104616            0
       Output:        235698          0      25219503            0
   Adaptive Statistics:
       Adaptive Adjusts:          0
       Adaptive Scans  :          0
       Adaptive Updates:          0
   Protocol eth-switch
     Flags: None

cli show lacp interfaces ae11
Aggregated interface: ae11
   LACP state:       Role   Exp   Def  Dist  Col  Syn  Aggr  Timeout  Activity
     ge-0/0/11      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast   Passive
     ge-0/0/11    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Slow    Active
     ge-1/0/11      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast   Passive
     ge-1/0/11    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Slow    Active
   LACP protocol:        Receive State  Transmit State          Mux State 
     ge-0/0/11                 Current   Slow periodic Collecting distributing
     ge-1/0/11                 Current   Slow periodic Collecting distributing

cli show lacp interfaces ae48
Aggregated interface: ae48
   LACP state:       Role   Exp   Def  Dist  Col  Syn  Aggr  Timeout  Activity
     xe-0/1/0       Actor    No    No    No   No  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
     xe-0/1/0     Partner    No    No    No   No   No    No     Slow    Active
     xe-1/1/0       Actor    No    No    No   No   No   Yes     Fast    Active
     xe-1/1/0     Partner    No    No    No   No   No    No     Slow    Active
   LACP protocol:        Receive State  Transmit State          Mux State 
     xe-0/1/0                  Current   Slow periodic           Attached
     xe-1/1/0                  Current   Slow periodic           Detached

show interfaces xe-0/1/0 
Physical interface: xe-0/1/0, Enabled, Physical link is Up
  Interface index: 206, SNMP ifIndex: 652
  Link-level type: Ethernet, MTU: 1514, LAN-PHY mode, Speed: 10Gbps, Duplex: Full-Duplex, BPDU Error: None,
  MAC-REWRITE Error: None, Loopback: Disabled, Source filtering: Disabled, Flow control: Disabled
  Device flags   : Present Running
  Interface flags: SNMP-Traps Internal: 0x0
  Link flags     : None
  CoS queues     : 8 supported, 8 maximum usable queues
  Current address: 78:19:f7:81:0d:33, Hardware address: 78:19:f7:81:0d:33
  Last flapped   : 2020-10-27 03:02:57 CET (03:18:08 ago)
  Input rate     : 1024 bps (1 pps)
  Output rate    : 0 bps (0 pps)
  Active alarms  : None
  Active defects : None
  Interface transmit statistics: Disabled

  Logical interface xe-0/1/0.0 (Index 147) (SNMP ifIndex 653)
    Flags: Up SNMP-Traps 0x0 Encapsulation: ENET2
    Protocol aenet, AE bundle: ae48.0

show interfaces xe-1/1/0    
Physical interface: xe-1/1/0, Enabled, Physical link is Up
  Interface index: 255, SNMP ifIndex: 651
  Link-level type: Ethernet, MTU: 1514, LAN-PHY mode, Speed: 10Gbps, Duplex: Full-Duplex, BPDU Error: None,
  MAC-REWRITE Error: None, Loopback: Disabled, Source filtering: Disabled, Flow control: Disabled
  Device flags   : Present Running
  Interface flags: SNMP-Traps Internal: 0x0
  Link flags     : None
  CoS queues     : 8 supported, 8 maximum usable queues
  Current address: 78:19:f7:81:0d:33, Hardware address: 78:fe:3d:d7:29:33
  Last flapped   : 2020-10-27 03:03:01 CET (03:18:09 ago)
  Input rate     : 1664 bps (1 pps)
  Output rate    : 0 bps (0 pps)
  Active alarms  : None
  Active defects : None
  Interface transmit statistics: Disabled

  Logical interface xe-1/1/0.0 (Index 184) (SNMP ifIndex 742)
    Flags: Up SNMP-Traps 0x0 Encapsulation: ENET2
    Protocol aenet, AE bundle: ae48.0
```

Best regards,

Alex

---

Edit 1:

When I disable LACP on ae48 then I can see incoming LACP packages on both interfaces with command "monitor traffic interface xe-0/1/0"

When I activate LACP passive again first I see no traffic and after a while one interface receive sometimes (about every 1 minute and 40 seconds) a LACP package.

messages logs how

```
Jun 24 10:36:41  dus3-switch-a mgd[15464]: UI_COMMIT_COMPLETED: commit complete
Jun 24 10:36:43  dus3-switch-a rpd[11601]: JTASK_SCHED_SLIP: 4 sec scheduler slip, user: 0 sec 35697 usec, system: 0 sec, 4154 usec
Jun 24 10:36:43  dus3-switch-a /kernel: ae_bundlestate_ifd_change: bundle ae48: bundle IFD minimum bandwidth or minimum links not met, Bandwidth (Current : Required) 0 : 1 Number of links (Current : Required) 0 : 1
Jun 24 10:36:43  dus3-switch-a /kernel: KERN_LACP_INTF_STATE_CHANGE: lacp_update_state_userspace: cifd xe-0/1/0 - DETACHED state - will not carry traffic
Jun 24 10:36:43  dus3-switch-a /kernel: KERN_LACP_INTF_STATE_CHANGE: lacp_update_state_userspace: cifd xe-1/1/0 - DETACHED state - will not carry traffic
Jun 24 10:36:43  dus3-switch-a cfmd[11598]: JTASK_SCHED_SLIP: 4 sec scheduler slip, user: 0 sec 3690 usec, system: 0 sec, 4665 usec
Jun 24 10:36:43  dus3-switch-a mib2d[11600]: SNMP_TRAP_LINK_DOWN: ifIndex 743, ifAdminStatus up(1), ifOperStatus down(2), ifName ae48
Jun 24 10:36:43  dus3-switch-a chassism[1213]: IFCM: no handler for command subtype 179
Jun 24 10:36:46  dus3-switch-a last message repeated 7 times
Jun 24 10:37:12  dus3-switch-a last message repeated 3 times
Jun 24 10:37:12  dus3-switch-a /kernel: KERN_LACP_INTF_STATE_CHANGE: lacp_update_state_userspace: cifd xe-1/1/0 - ATTACHED state - acting as standby link
Jun 24 10:37:12  dus3-switch-a chassism[1213]: IFCM: no handler for command subtype 179
Jun 24 10:37:12  dus3-switch-a chassism[1213]: IFCM: no handler for command subtype 179
```

traffic on xe-0/1/0

```
10:40:32.266067  In LACPv1, length 60
10:40:57.466008 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:41:25.997033 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:41:53.032952 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:42:12.268876  In LACPv1, length 60
10:42:21.422895 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:42:47.105560 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:43:16.492994 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:43:43.517998 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:43:52.270721  In LACPv1, length 60
```

on xe-1/1/0

```
10:40:13.209918 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:40:41.009994 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:41:06.792957 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:41:35.413990 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:42:02.572153 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:42:30.853607 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:42:57.300007 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:43:26.552951 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:43:56.474951 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
10:44:24.423500 Out LLDP, name dus3-switch-a, length 60
        [|LLDP]
```

show LACP interfaces ae48

```
Aggregated interface: ae48
    LACP state:       Role   Exp   Def  Dist  Col  Syn  Aggr  Timeout  Activity
      xe-0/1/0       Actor    No    No    No   No   No   Yes     Fast   Passive
      xe-0/1/0     Partner    No    No    No   No   No    No     Slow    Active
      xe-1/1/0       Actor    No    No    No   No  Yes   Yes     Fast   Passive
      xe-1/1/0     Partner    No    No    No   No   No    No     Slow    Active
    LACP protocol:        Receive State  Transmit State          Mux State 
      xe-0/1/0                  Current   Slow periodic           Detached
      xe-1/1/0                  Current   Slow periodic           Attached
```